# Zeppelin: Problematic table display when mixing with strings

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

For example, if I use z.show() to output table directly

```
%pyspark
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 0, "2018-06-03", "2018-06-03"),
    (1, 1, "2018-06-04", "2018-06-04"),
    (2, 10, "2018-06-03", None),
    (4, 1, "2018-06-05", "2018-06-01")])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "product_name", "product_name2")
print("test print string 1")
z.show(df)
z.show(df.describe())
```

The output is fine, like this

[image]

However, if I add a string between the output tables

```
%pyspark
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 0, "2018-06-03", "2018-06-03"),
    (1, 1, "2018-06-04", "2018-06-04"),
    (2, 10, "2018-06-03", None),
    (4, 1, "2018-06-05", "2018-06-01")])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "product_name", "product_name2")
print("test print string 1")
z.show(df)
print("test print string 2") # If I add this
z.show(df.describe())
```

The output turns to this, (no table showed)

[image]

I want to know, how can I mix string and Zeppelin's table show together?

I think the problem maybe due to the string causes the Zeppelin's table show ill-formated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, this is an issue of zeppelin. The workaround is to add '%text' to specify the output type explicitly as following

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 0, "2018-06-03", "2018-06-03"),
    (1, 1, "2018-06-04", "2018-06-04"),
    (2, 10, "2018-06-03", None),
    (4, 1, "2018-06-05", "2018-06-01")])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "product_name", "product_name2")
print("test print string 1")
z.show(df)
print("%text test print string 2") # If I add this
z.show(df.describe())
```